# Load div contents into a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value which is created around the middle of a page and I want to show it in the header...

So, I have the following:

```
<div id=lines style=display:none;><? echo ($line_no-1); ?></div>
```

Now, I want to load that value ($line_no-1) into a div in the header. So as you can see I store it into a div, turn off the display, and then use the following to try to load it into the div above

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lines2").load("/ #lines");
    });
</script>
```

It simply doesn't work and I think I've tried every combination now

What I'd rather do is simply load the variable into the div above but have searched and searched for a way to do this with no luck.

Comment: this looks very sloppy to me, but why aren't you doing something simple like `$('#lines2').html($('#lines').html());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merely reproduce the text from the `lines` div into the `lines2` div:

```
$('#lines2').text($('#lines').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

`.load` means something else. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#lines2").html($('#lines').html());
});
</script>
```

If you want to append it instead, do:

```
$("#lines2").append($('#lines').html());
```

Comment: you can actually use `.text()` instead of `.html()`, since it's only a number (no html structure)